# Configurable products not searchable in Magento

Tags: magento

My site has a need to have all products as configurable with no associated products (for now). So the site is mostly used as a catalog. We use configurable as opposed to simple products because we anticipate in the future we will add the associated products.

However, I notice that configurable products without associated products are not searchable. I tried to work around this by looking at this piece of code inside the Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Search_Collection class.

```
// search in catalogindex for products as part of configurable/grouped/bundle products (current store)
$where = array();
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $where[] = sprintf('(attribute_id=%d AND value=%d)', $option['attribute_id'], $option['option_id']);
}
if ($where) {
    $selects[] = (string)$this->getConnection()->select()
        ->from($resource->getTableName('catalogindex/eav'), 'entity_id')
        ->where(implode(' OR ', $where))
        ->where("store_id={$storeId}");
}
```

I tried to comment out this code but still returns empty. Which code should I comment out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the visibility is set to "Catalog, Search" and then under Inventory select "In stock" under stock availability or override the "Manage Stock" setting to "No".

Then of course ensure that indexes and cache are up to date.

Comment: Thanks, confirm all those, but still not searchable.